# Search for more than one word in one cell

Tags: excel, search, full-text-search, multiple-columns

I have a list of patients with codes for all of the procedures they had eg `K567`, `H765`, `Y234`. I would like to search all cells in the procedure column (J) for two different procedures together. So for the example above, I would want to copy the entire row to another spreadsheet if it had both `K567` and `H765`. eg

```
patient number- admission date- diagnosis-    procedure code

1-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H763,Y239,Y876
2-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H769,Y233,Y874
3-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H761,Y231,Y874
4-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H765,Y239,Y876
5-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H765,Y233,Y876
```

with my procedure criteria as `Y874` and `K567`, ideally, the new worksheet would be:

```
patient number- admission date- diagnosis-    procedure code

2-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H769,Y233,Y874
3-               1/1/14-          K47-        K567,H761,Y231,Y874
```

I have 4000 patients to go through.

To complicate matters, I have a range of codes, so instead of `Y874` and `K567`, I *really* want `Y871` or `Y872` or `Y873` or `Y874` or `Y875` or `Y876` and `K567`.

If that isn't possible, any variation to make my life easier would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the picture, I did it in the same worksheet for clarity.

[image]

Procedure codes to look for are in F1:F2

In G2 write the array formula (Ctrl Shift Enter to enter this formula):

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1;$D$2:$D$6))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2;$D$2:$D$6))>1;ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1;"");ROWS($A$2:A2));"")
```

Copy this formula down till you sure it will cover the maximum possible matches.

Now in H2 write the formula:

```
=IF($G2="";"";INDEX(A$2:A$6;$G2))
```

Copy the formula right till K2 and then down at will (just like the first formula)

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

Answer (score 0):

A Vba user defined function using regular expressions (Regex) would allow you to do this, just set your regex pattern to be something like letter-number-number-number. You could then look for matches. Count >1.

EDIT - the whoever downvoted this response - would you care to explain why?  Simply downvoting without explanation does nothing to help find the best solution to a problem.